# Volumetrics Tab Has no checkbox

Tags: volumetrics

I'm following a tutorial to make fog in my scene. I've tried adding both the principle volume and Volume scatter node to the material output. neither generates fog in the render view or lookdev. It also appears that my volumetrics tab doesn't have a checkbox to turn it on or off like the tutorial says to click. Am I missing something here?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volumetrics panel is collapsed in the *Render Properties* panel.

Expand it to reveal the check boxes ...

[image: Volumetrics Panel]

Comment: I also tried checking those boxes to no avail, not to mention I fiddled with every setting to see if one would change something but nothing happened.

Comment: Honestly, no idea what I did different but I restarted from scratch and was able to get it to work first try. Womp womp.

Comment: Sometimes the way with blender, you fiddle so many settings that you can't remember what you've messed with.  If the answer is satisfactory, please accept it so that others know that it is closed.

Comment: It turns out I was applying the principled volumetric node to the world output and not the object output.